# A sequence of $n^2$ real numbers which contains no monotonic subsequence of more than $n$ terms

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I'm following a Combinatorics course at the moment, and have recent proved the [Erdős–Szekeres Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem) (or, at least, some variation of):

> A sequence of length $n^2 + 1$ either contains an increasing subsequence of length $n+1$, or a decreasing one of length $n+1$.

I have been set an exercise to prove the following:

> For each natural number $n$, find a sequence of $n^2$ real numbers which contains no monotonic subsequence of more than $n$ terms.

I can naively / informally how to do this, but no method which would seem to involve any sort of Graph / Ramsey Theory.  I'm assuming that I'll have to use Erdős–Szekeres, since I'm in a Combinatorics course, or notice something about its proof, to come up with a formal construction of the sequence, but can't see how I'd go about it.

Would using Erdős–Szekeres be the right way to go about this, or is there a different / simpler combinatorial way to explore?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to look at the proof of the ES theorem, it will give you the construction you need.

Comment: also try $n=1,$ then $n=2,$ then $n=3.$ Maybe you can find a pattern out of those.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**:
$$\def\b{\color{red}{\bullet}\ }\def\w{\circ\ }
\eqalign{\w\ \w\w\w\w\w\b\w\w\cr \w\ \w\w\w\w\w\w\b\w\cr \w\ \w\w\w\w\w\w\w\b\cr
        \w\ \w\w\b\w\w\w\w\w\cr \w\ \w\w\w\b\w\w\w\w\cr \w\ \w\w\w\w\b\w\w\w\cr
        \b\ \w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\cr \w\ \b\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\cr \w\ \w\b\w\w\w\w\w\w\cr}$$

Comment: Yes, this was the 'informal' idea that I had; glad to see what I was thinking was indeed on the right lines.

I've thought about it some more and been able to generalise it a bit more, so thanks for confirming my thoughts!